# Calculation of variables

Tags: regression, random-variable

This question might be very basic, but yet it makes me wonder, so I wanted to ask you for an opinion.

How much calculation is allowed or desired when creating a variable? Are there at all any limitations? Is it perhaps desired to "mess" with data as little as possible and use it in its purest form?

For example, if for any unit in our sample we have three separate types of information - a,b,c; Is it ok to calculate a new variable with the equation (a*b)/c and use it as such?

Also, would a variable calculated as =a*b give  the same results when tested as an interaction between a and b? Or are those two things completely different?

Comment: if $(a*b)/c$ is meaningful, then it should be acceptable as a predictor; such variables can occur regularly in economic contexts, for example.

Comment: Thanks Glen. One more question - would using the same data in calculating two different variables cause any problems? For example, if I calculate one variable as a/b, and the other as a*c. thanks again!

Comment: Well, it could cause strong dependence in some circumstances, and in some particular cases people might have issues relating to interpretation (it's a very general question so it's hard to say much on that). But in some cases it could be reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

The amount of calculation "allowed" depends on context. Some variables have a "pure" form that is widely accepted. Others don't. For example, factor analyzing a bunch of variables and creating one or more latent variables and then using the those latent variables is "allowed" and is certainly a lot of "messing" with the  variables. Same with doing principal component analysis and partial least squares.

As for interaction, $a*b$ is by far the most common way of looking at interactions.